# Creating Gtk.ApplicationWindow from glade

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, glade

I'm using Python 3.6, and I'm trying to create an application window from a glade xml file like this:

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("ui/window.glade")
win = builder.get_object("window1")
win.set_application(self)
win.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
win.show_all()
```

However, this way the window does not retain the menu bar, that I set in the application do_startup, like this:

```
builder.add_from_file("ui/menu.glade")
set_menubar(self.builder.get_object("menubar"))
```

However, if I try to create a window with this class:

```
class MyWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="MyTitle", application=app)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(600, 500)

# application do_activate function
win = MyWindow(self)
win.show_all()
```

the menu is shown. How can I add the menu to the window created from Gtk.Builder? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

is "window1" in your glade file an ApplicationWindow ?
Using Application.set_menubar() you can specify a menubar that will be shown by Gtk.ApplicationWindow's.